# Function Not Being Recognized Within My If Statement

Tags: powershell, compiler-errors

So I'm trying to learn PowerShell and trying to create a File Integrity Monitor with the help of a guide, but I'm getting an error in my **if** statement saying that my function isn't recognized even though I created the function first since to my knowledge, Powershell works off a "top-down" method. I spent some time trying to figure it out myself and also using resources such as Google of course but couldn't get a solution. Any help would be appreciated alongside just general tips for Powershell/coding if you have any. Also a little new to Stack Overflow in general so apologies if I have poor formatting for this. Thank you.

This is my code that's producing the error. The call for the function within the **foreach** is the primary issue.

```
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "What would you like to do?"
Write-Host "A) Collect a new baseline"
Write-Host "B) Begin monitoring files with a saved baseline?"
Write-Host ""

$answer = Read-Host "Please enter 'A' or 'B'"
Write-Host ""

function CalculateFileHashes ($filepath) {
    $filehash = Get-FileHash -Path $filepath -Algorithm SHA256
    return $filehash
}

if ($answer -eq "A".ToUpper()) {
    # Calculate a hash from the selected files and store them into baseline.txt
    # Collect files within targeted folder/location
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path E:\VSCodePowershellFIM\FIMtest

    # For each file, calculate the hash, and write them to baseline.txt
    foreach ($f in $files) {
        $hash = CalculateFileHashes $f.FullName
        "$hash.Path | $hash.Hash"
    }
 }
elseif ($answer -eq "B".ToUpper()) {
    # Begin monitoring files using the saved baseline
    Write-Host "testing... i'm watchin..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry, thank you for the advice and link for clarification. I added an answer that has the full, actual code with it as the link suggested!

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code other than `"$hash.Path | $hash.Hash"` which should be `"$($hash.Path) | $($hash.Hash)"` and `Get-FileHash -Path $filepath -Algorithm SHA256` which should be `$filepath | Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256`. Also `Get-ChildItem` should have `-File` otherwise you're risking trying to calculate the hash of a directory which will clearly fail.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thank you for the input! Appreciate the advice/corrections and also seems quicker to write and cleaner looking such as the `$filepath |` suggestion.

Comment: so when you do `$hash.Path` for example you want to get the value of the `.Path` property but without `$(...)` that expression cannot be evaluated, in other words, the value cannot be expanded in your string (`"...."`). you can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Okay, thank you very much!

Comment: The error has been fixed now with the help, much appreciated and thank you for your time! @SantiagoSquarzon